# Merge cases in an SPSS data set

Tags: spss

I have two SPSS data sets that have the exact same variables. When I merge the data sets via "add cases", there are some cases in the merged data set that refer to the same person. The problem is that these cases are not perfect duplicates of each other. Say, for instance, there are two cases called 1 and 2 that refer to the same person, and two variables called A and B. 1 has a value for A, but its value for B is missing, where 2 has a value for B but its value for A is missing. Is there a way to merge 1 and 2 so that I end up with a single case that has a value for both A and B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is aggregate by person and get the maximum of each value - which would combine the two cases of each person but get the existing values from both cases:

```
aggregate outfile=* /break=personID /A B=max(A B).
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks like it will work although I can't check it right now. Just one question: Will this also work when the variables are nominal, i.e. does SPSS treat a missing value as "smaller" than an existing value regardless of scale?

Comment: It will work with strings/nominals too. Something to note though - make sure that this is only for cases where one case has a value and the other doesn't - if both cases have values, the maximum may not (always) be the right choice.